# How to prove that $\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} \frac{xy^5}{x^4+y^6}=0$

Tags: limits

How can I apply the squeeze theorem to show
$$\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} \frac{xy^5}{x^4+y^6}=0$$

Comment: How have you applied the squeeze theorem?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you'll get an answer if you show us that you made some effort.

Comment: Take the equivalent expression $$\frac{1}{\frac{x^3}{y^5}+\frac yx}$$

Comment: try it with $$y=tx$$

Comment: Well trying with $y=tx$ gives the claimed limit, but it does not show that the limit is unique. There are some examples where approaching by any line gives some unique limit, but approaching with another curve (quadratic for instance) gives another one...

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Why propagate this ultra classical misconception? Because you really think that if $f(x,tx)\to0$ when $x\to0$, for every $t$, then $f(x,y)\to(0,0)$ when $(x,y)\to(0,0)$? Exercise for you: Find a counterexample.

Comment: @Piquito What's next?

Comment: I think the order of increase of $y^5$ being greater than that of $x^3$ the quotient gives infinite so whatever be the quotient $\dfrac yx$ you have $\infty$ in the denominator.

Comment: @Piquito Sounds awfully vague, no?

Comment: I understand it could "sounds awfully vague" for many people; not for me. Regards.

Comment: @Piquito Care to explain what you meant in this first comment then, for the understanding of people who are not yourself? (Unrelated: Please use @, unless you want your comments to be missed by the user they are addressed at.)

Comment: There are levels of knowledge, that's all.

Comment: @Piquito Sorry but you are not making any sense. No big deal.

Answer (score 2):

If $|x|\geqslant|y|^{4/3}$ and $x\ne0$, $$\left|\frac{xy^5}{x^4+y^6}\right|\leqslant\left|\frac{xy^5}{x^4}\right|=\frac{|y|^5}{|x|^3}\leqslant|x|^{3/4}$$
If $|x|\leqslant|y|^{4/3}$ and $y\ne0$, $$\left|\frac{xy^5}{x^4+y^6}\right|\leqslant\left|\frac{xy^5}{y^6}\right|=\frac{|x|}{|y|}\leqslant|y|^{1/3}$$
Thus, for every $(x,y)\ne(0,0)$, $$\left|\frac{xy^5}{x^4+y^6}\right|\leqslant|x|^{3/4}+|y|^{1/3}$$ The limit of the LHS when $(x,y)\to(0,0)$ follows.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: for $xy = 0$ the expression is zero, for $xy\ne 0$ bound the denominator using the weighted AGM inequality with weights 1 and 3:
$$|x||y|^{9/2}\le\frac{x^4 + 3y^6}4\le x^4 + y^6.$$

Comment: but this doesnt show that the limit is zero. Observe that the RHS can define any non-negative value for a chosen path $(x,y)\to(0,0)$